# Jquery ischecked não funciona

Tags: jquery

Possuo o seguinte checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="responderam" id="responderam" value="1" onchange="Filtra()"  /> Mostrar apenas quem respondeu
```

E a função que ele chama vai atualizar a página setando uma flag

```
function Filtra() {     

    var respondeu = "";
    var valor = $("#responderam").val();

    if($("#responderam").is(':checked')){
        respondeu = 1;
    }
    else {
        respondeu = 0;
    }
}
```

Mas este IF não funciona de maneira alguma. E a função também não pega de jeito nenhum o valor "1" do checkbox mesmo se eu checka-lo.
Estou usando o Jquery 1.8.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Já vi respostas em outras perguntas mas não dá certo.

Comment: Abaixo do respondeu = 1 / 0 ; coloque: alert(valor)

Comment: Diz "undefined"

Comment: Que estranho. Esta function Filtra() está no arquivo scripts.js e não está sendo chamada diretamente na página.

Comment: O elemento `#responderam` existe no momento em que tenta usar?

Comment: @LucasCosta concordo, se existir, funciona. https://jsfiddle.net/jwvh3eo0/

Comment: Ele não identifica o elemento #responderam. Não diz que não existe mas também não consigo pegar nenhum valor dele.

Comment: Por acaso existe outro elemento com o mesmo id na página?

Comment: Não, somente ele possui este nome. Ja tentei com nomes diferentes mas mesmo assim não vai.

Comment: @RenanKaicLopes a resposta que o Leandro enviou está funcionando normal, assim também eu deixei uma outra resposta como alternativa.

Comment: O problema podem ser três: 1) Não ter nenhum elemento com o *id* responderam. 2) Existir mais de um elemento com o *id* responderam . 3) O elemento *id* responderam não existir no momento do uso, para esse caso a solução é `$(document).ready(function() { // checked teste aqui });`

Comment: A solução do Bruno.H funcionou. Se eu tento pelo seletor $("#responderam") ele não funciona e nem identifica o elemento (mas também não dá erro), somente se eu passar o valor como parâmetro para a função. O que pode ser isso?

Comment: @RenanKaicLopes Você chegou a tentar conforme o 2º método que postei na minha resposta para ver se funciona corretamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está funcionando normalmente, segue exemplo exibindo um `alert` de acordo com o estado do `ckeckbox` e com jQuery 1.8:

```js
function Filtra() {     
    var respondeu = "";
    var valor = $("#responderam").val();

    if($("#responderam").is(':checked')){
        respondeu = 1;
        alert (respondeu);
    }
    else {
        respondeu = 0;
        alert (respondeu);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="responderam" id="responderam" value="1" onchange="Filtra()"  /> Mostrar apenas quem respondeu
```

2ª alternativa - chamando a função pelo tipo do `input` caso na sua página **não exista** outros `checkbox`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':checkbox').change(function() {   
    var respondeu = "";
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        respondeu = 1;
        alert (respondeu);
    }
    else {
        respondeu = 0;
        alert (respondeu);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="responderam" id="responderam" value="1"/> Mostrar apenas quem respondeu
```

3ª alternativa - mantendo o `id` do `checkbox`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#responderam').change(function() {   
    var respondeu = "";
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        respondeu = 1;
        alert (respondeu);
    }
    else {
        respondeu = 0;
        alert (respondeu);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="responderam" id="responderam" value="1"/> Mostrar apenas quem respondeu
```

Comment: Isso é, se existir o elemento `#responderam`, o que parece ser o problema do AP.

Comment: Funcionou sim a segunda alternativa Leandro. Mas eu preciso realmente verificar se o checkbox está marcado em outras funções e infelizmente não tem como eu usar o .change para setar o valor. Mas não sei pq não consigo pegar se ele está selecionado ou não pq ele vem como undefined.

Comment: @RenanKaicLopes Mas o `.change` tem o mesmo efeito e funciona da mesma forma que o `onchange="Filtra()" `  utilizado no seu código, a única diferença é que não terá que colocar a chamada da função `onchange`   dentro do `input`.

Comment: Eu acabei decidindo refazer toda a função escrevendo do zero e agora funcionou e ele está pegando o valor do input #responderam. A função que coloquei na pergunta foi apenas uma parte da Filtra(). Não sei o que acabei mudando que no final deu tudo certo. Mas obrigado pelo acompanhamento Leandro.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function Filtra(evt) {  
  var respondeu = "";
  var valor =  $(evt).val();
    if($(evt).is(':checked')){
        respondeu = 1;
        $(evt).val(1);
        alert (respondeu);
    }
    else {
        respondeu = 0;
        $(evt).val(0);
        alert (respondeu);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="responderam" id="responderam"  onchange="Filtra(this)"  /> Mostrar apenas quem respondeu
```

Comment: A solução por hora foi esta. Se eu tento pelo seletor $("#responderam") ele não funciona e nem identifica o elemento (mas também não dá erro), somente se eu passar o valor como parâmetro para a função. O que pode ser isso?

Comment: Bom desculpa, não domino jQuery para te fala o porque, só utilizei um pouco do que sei para tentar te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Outra alternativa

```js
$("#responderam").change(function() {
  var respondeu = "";
  var valor = $("#responderam").val();
  if(this.checked) {
    respondeu = 1;
    alert(respondeu);
  } else {
    respondeu = 0;
    alert(respondeu);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="responderam" id="responderam" value="1"  /> Mostrar apenas quem respondeu
```